# "Payment Resouce not found" with square on checkout page

Tags: php, woocommerce, square

On the WooCommerce checkout page, I'm using Square card payment. However, when a customer attempts to pay with a saved card, the payment does not complete, and the page remains in a processing state. I've noticed the following error in the network:

{"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"NOT_FOUND","detail":"Resource not found.","field":"payment_source"}]}

Could you please guide me on what the exact issue might be? I've been trying to resolve this problem for the last three days.

Thank you.

On the staging environment, its working fine, But on the production we are facing this issue.

Comment: As this seems a bug related to Square card payment, it should be reported to the plugin support pages.

Comment: Their support service is not good